# What is a 16 bit real mode OS?

Tags: operating-system, bootloader

I am working on making a boot loader. I don't know anything till now. I am learning. What is a 16 bit Real mode OS ? What does "Real Mode" means

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode

Answer (score 3):

Read more about [X86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) and its [real mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode)

In short, it is painful, and exists today for historical reasons.

Why do you work on a boot loader? Did you consider using [GNU GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) to load whatever kernel software you want to load? At least, study the source of some existing boot loader like Grub or [LILO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_%28boot_loader%29)

Comment: its an academic project..  learning stuff ..

Comment: My feeling is that testing boot loaders is painful. Boot loaders depend upon the BIOS and the hardware, and they vary a lot.

Comment: "Real mode" in early x86 processors was a necessary evil.  Remember, the only software available for the x86 processors was 16-bit real mode stuff, and unless Intel/AMD wanted to write and market their own OS and compilers and such they had to support the existing software.  So the 286 and 386 were built to boot in 8086-mimic mode and then be switchable into the "fancier" modes, and the 386 was designed to allow 8086-style programs to run in a "sandbox" inside an OS that "spoke" 386.

Answer (score 2):

"16 bits" means that that's the size of a "word" as recognized by the CPU (though memory may be organized into bytes, etc).  It also implies that the memory address will not be substantially larger than 16 bits, but that gets to be a fuzzy area.

"Real mode" means that the memory is addressed without using any memory-mapping hardware.  Ie, the address 1234 in a CPU register will, when used to reference memory, fetch the value at the physical location 1234 in RAM.  Usually also implied is that there is little in the way of memory "protection" -- at most just a CPU register than reserves space above or below a certain address as "read-only".

Old original MS DOS would be considered to fall into this category, as would the original Apple II operating system, and many others that are mostly forgotten.  Even some fairly large early computers (ie, multiple 6-foot-tall racks of equipment) operated in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at [James Molloy's Kernel Development Tutorial](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html) which introduces you to using GRUB and booting your kernel you can learn to write.